# window label is not printing : Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create two windows.

**Behaviour of windows:**

Window1 has a `label` and a `button`. When I click on that  `button`, 2nd window has to open. 2nd window have a `label`.

**Problem:**

`Label` in 2nd window is not  appearing.

**Code:**

```
def window1():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.geometry("200x200")
    root.title("Window1")
    var = tkinter.StringVar()

    tkinter.Label(root,  textvariable = var, bg = "red").grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    var.set("This is window1")

    tkinter.Button(root, text = "Button1", command = OnBut).grid(row =  0, column = 1)

    root.mainloop()

def OnBut():
    window2()

def window2():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.title("Window2")
    root.geometry("250x250")

    var = tkinter.StringVar()

    tkinter.Label(root,  textvariable = var, bg = "blue").grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 3, pady = 3)
    tkinter.Button(root, text = "Button", command = OnBut).grid(row =  0, column = 1, padx  =3, pady = 3)
    var.set("This is window2")       #not appearing <-- problem

    root.mainloop()

window1()
```

when I call `window2` seperately, its working fine. Why `label` not printing in 2nd window, by clicking on `button`?

Comment: root is not defined in the `onBut()` method

Comment: sorry @PadraicCunningham. Now I updated correctly.

Comment: you changed the `onBut` method, no issue is `window2` takes argument.

Comment: how many times are you going to change your code?? root1 is not defined. What exactly is supposed to happen? When I click button on window1 it opens window2, what else should happen?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham. Editing completed

Comment: I see a second window when I click the button, second window has a button and text that says "This is window2", what else is missing?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  but it's not  working to me.

Comment: what happens for you, any error?

Comment: `This is window2` is not printing @PadraicCunningham

Comment: You are using Tkinter wrong. You shouldn't ever create a second instance of `Tk`. If you need more than one window, create instances of `Toplevel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need a real function for your `command` in this case. This is what `lambda`s are made for -- callbacks!

Remove your `onBut` function (which is the problem anyway, since `root` isn't defined there) and replace your `command` in each button with:

```
command = lambda: window2(root)
```

Currently, when you call `onBut`, it tries to do:

```
window2(root)
# HELP I DON'T KNOW WHAT root IS!!
```

This throws a `NameError` on my copy. Your code may vary.

Since you're editing willy nilly, let me just write you some working code.

```
import tkinter

def run():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.title("Window1")
    s_var = tkinter.StringVar()
    tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = s_var).pack()
    tkinter.Button(root, text = "Button", command = lambda: makewindow(root)).pack()
    s_var.set("Window #1")

def makewindow(root):
    top = tkinter.Toplevel(root)
    top.title("Window2")
    s_var = tkinter.StringVar()
    tkinter.Label(top, textvariable = s_var).pack()
    tkinter.Button(top, text = "Button", command = lambda: makewindow(root)).pack()
    s_var.set("Window #2")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Comment: @SGG I'm afraid you don't seem to really grasp the problem so I don't think I can help you. You've changed your code to make it more and more wrong =/

Comment: I' m sorry. Now you can try.

Comment: @SGG I already answered your question correctly. Your new code introduced a slew of new bugs. For instance you now have two `tkinter.Tk` objects which is a Bad Thing.

Comment: what if I have `tkinter.tk` objects. both are different, right?

Comment: @SGG you can't drive two cars at once, can you? Similarly, don't try and run two instances of `Tk` at once.